# Contar registros de una tabla a partir de un Array con php sql

Tags: php, array, sql

Necesito crear una consulta SQL que me cuente el total de registros encontrados según el ID.

```
$parroquia = $_POST['parroquia'];

SELECT COUNT(*) total FROM pagos WHERE parroquia = '$prroquia';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$fila = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
echo 'Número de total de pagos en la parroquia '.$parroquia.': ' . $fila['total'];
```

algo parecido quiero hacer, pero el ejemplo de arriba se esta contando los registro de un sola parroquia.
pero si se selecciona varias parroquia cuanto pagos registrados serian por cada parroquia seleccionada. ejemplo:

tengo un select multiple que devuelve:

`$parroquia= $_POST['parroquia'];`

que es lo mismo a esto:

`$parroquia = [13,17,19];`

como se cuantos pagos hay en total de la parroquia 13, y de la parroquia 17 y 19?
lo se hacer cuando es una sola parroquia, pero en este caso el select multiple devuelve un array

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si entendí bien tu requerimiento, puedes generar un arreglo en donde almacenes, con el identificador de la parroquia como index, los valores de registros de cada una de las parroquias. Te dejo un ejemplo de como se podría hacer.

```
<?php
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");

$parroquias = [1, 2, 3];

/* verificar la conexión */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Conexión fallida: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

foreach ($parroquias as $parroquia) {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, "SELECT parroquia FROM pagos WHERE parroquia = ?");
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 's', $parroquia);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    mysqli_stmt_store_result($stmt);

    $row_cnt = mysqli_stmt_num_rows($stmt);
    $parroquias_total[$parroquia] = $row_cnt;
}
/* cerrar la conexión */
mysqli_close($link);
```

Los resultados de cada parroquia los tendrías en el array `$parroquias_total` en donde mediante el identificador de la parroquia puedes ingresar al resultado. Por ejemplo, puedes acceder a el total de registros de la parroquia 13 mediante el siguiente codigo: `$parroquias_total[13]`.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

Comment: como imprimo el resultado.? donde coloco el echo

Comment: Después del foreach que es donde ya se lleno la información de cada uno de las parroquias.

Comment: Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\ejemplo\ejemplo.php on line 66
Array
eso me sale. después del foreach  coloque: echo $parroquias_total;

Comment: si quieres ver todo el arreglo puedes hacer un `var_dump($parroquias_total);` si quieres ver un solo resultado, tal como escribi en la ultima parte de la respuesta, puedes hacerlo mediante `echo $parroquias_total[parroquia];` en donde `parroquia` es el identificador de la parroquia de la que quieres saber la cantidad de registros.

Comment: ya funciona. me devuelve un array: array(2) { [15]=> int(1) [13]=> int(2) }.
ahora como mando ese resultado mediante json? asi: echo json_encode($parroquias_total); ? par mandarlo medinte ajax.

Comment: porque quiero mostrar algo asi:
Parroquia El diamante: 15
Parroquia San José : 02
Parroquia Puerto Alegre: 05

Comment: En donde quieres mostrar esos resultados?

Comment: ya lo resolví :) gracias. fue muy útil tu ayuda